# Select singleton relationships from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql

I have two tables with a many-to-many relationship.  The two tables are actually a `dataset` table that encodes metadata about a dataset, and an `aggregates` table, that keeps track of pre-aggregated data (my `dataset`s are large, and the way they get displayed in the UI is complex, so I am needing to do certain aggregations ahead of time).  It may be the case that `aggregates` happen over many `dataset`s, and a single `dataset` may belong to multiple `aggregates`, so there is a many-to-many relationship.  However, I will frequently want to aggregate over A SINGLE `dataset`.  This means that the entries in my `aggregates_dataset` association table for which the `aggregates` entry has EXACTLY ONE corresponding `dataset` are going to be the most frequently accessed, and this uniqueness is their defining property.  What is the most efficient way to select these `aggregates` that have exactly one dataset?

Here is a contrived analogy example using the usual fake tables:

```
products:

|    id    |   name    |
------------------------
| 1        | a         |
| 2        | b         |
| 3        | c         |
| 4        | d         |
```

```
categories:

| id | name     |
-----------------
| 1  | ab       |
| 2  | abc      |
| 3  | b        |
| 4  | d        |
| 5  | b        |
```

```
product_categories:

|  product_id  |  category_id  |
--------------------------------
| 1            | 1             |
| 2            | 1             |
| 1            | 2             |
| 2            | 2             |
| 3            | 2             |
| 2            | 3             |
| 4            | 4             |
| 2            | 5             |
```

Given product id=2, I would like to be able to get categories id=3 and 5, because although product id=2 is in four different categories, categories 3 and 5 have ONLY product id=2 in them.

I can achieve this with a CTE that `GROUP BY` `product_categories.category_id` to `COUNT` the number of products in each category, but this `GROUP BY` `COUNT` operation is relatively expensive.  Is there a more direct way to obtain product id=2's "special categories"?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid a `group by ... having count(*) = 1`, but what indexes have you defined on `product_categories`? Also, please show your attempt.

Comment: Add tag for RDMBS used.

Comment: You could do a NOT EXISTS for product id <> 2